# how to bind/connect multiple UDP socket

Tags: c, sockets, udp

My initial UDP socket is binded to 127.0.0.1:9898.

The first time that I get notified of incoming data by epoll/kqueue, I do recvfrom() and I fill a struct sockaddr called `peer_name` that contain the peer informations (ip:port).

Then I create a new UPD socket using socket(),

then I bind() this newly created socket to the same ip:port (127.0.0.1:9898) than my original socket.

then I connect my newly created socket using connect() to the peer who just sent me something. I have the information in the struct sockaddr called `peer_name`.

I then add my newly created socket in my epoll/kqueue vector and wait for notification.

I would expect to ONLY receive UDP frame from the peer i'm ""connected to"".

1/ does `netstat -a -p udp` is suppose to show me the IP:PORT of the peer my newly created socket is ""connected to"" ?

2/ I'm probably doing something wrong since after creating my new socket, this socket receive all incoming UDP packets destinated to the IP:PORT I'm binded to, regardless of the source peer IP:PORT.

I would like to see a working example of what I'm trying to do :)
or any hint on what I'm doing wrong.

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/unix-socket-faq/unix-socket-faq-5.html

"Does doing a connect() call affect the receive behaviourof the socket? 
Yes, in two ways. First, only datagrams from your "connected peer" are returned. All others arriving at your port are not delivered to you.

But most importantly, a UDP socket must be connected to receive ICMP errors. Pp. 748-749 of "TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 2" give all the gory details on why this is so."

Answer (score 1):

**connect(2)** on a UDP socket just sets the default destination address of the socket (where the data will be sent if you use **write(2)** or **send(2)** on the socket).  It has no other effect -- you can still send packets to other addresses with **sendto(2)** or **sendmsg(2)** and you'll still see packets sent from any address.

So it doesn't really make any sense to open a new socket on the port -- for every packet received, you need to look at the source address to see if it comes from an address you've seen already (and thus belongs to that logical stream) or is a new address (a new logical stream).

Comment: Just to be sure, I'm talking about the server side. The Idea, is that the new socket will receive all the data from a specific client. So it's why I connect() my new socket to the source client IP:PORT. 

A socket as a sockname and a peername. The sockname is the ADDR:PORT the socket is binded to, and the peername is the ADDR:PORT the socket is associated to (using connect()) and thus send() knows to who sending the data. getsockname(), getpeername().

Comment: @nicboul: Yes.  What Chris is pointing out is that `connect()` on a UDP socket is generally only useful on the *client* side, where a single socket is only talking to one peer.  It is unhelpful on the server side.

Comment: @Chris  I amy be nit-picking, but I am not sure I agree with your statement.  I think the connect has the effect of a remote-addr bind so that you may restrict traffic on that socket to messages from a specific client.  I am basing that in an `strace nc -4lu $((0x4444))`, followed by `grep 4444 /proc/net/udp` (in a different terminal), before and after the first message is received.  `nc` will not accept messages from other clients.

Comment: @Chris, I agree with @nhed - I have written a simple test app which `connect`s to the first `sockaddr` it gets back from a blocking `recvfrom` call; initiating multiple `sendto` calls from different sockets results in only the first socket's data being received